# Encoding Hebrew string from HTML in PowerShell

Tags: html, powershell

I got a rather simple task from my client, however I am stack on this tiny detail. My task is to creat a PowerShell script that read a list of user names , find them in Active Directory and then send them a mail with an HTML file as the body of that mail.
So far it wasn't a problem, however the company is in Israel and therefore the HTML file needs to be in Hebrew. When I tested it, the testing mail replaced all of the hebrew latters with '?'. I tried then to use encodinghh did  replaced the text with gibrish ,yet still no Hebrew.
I'm sure it is just a matter of finding the correct encoding, but I didn't find one that do the job.

My code:

```
$List = Get-Content C:\Users\usf45276\Desktop\Sander\list.txt
$FromAdress = #mail
$Creds = (Get-Credential "$FromAdress")
$SMTP = #smtp server
$encoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False
$Body = Get-Content C:\Users\usf45276\Desktop\Sander\body.html -Raw


foreach($Item in $List){
    # Get the user and his mail from the list
    $User = Get-ADUser -Filter {SAMAccountName -like $Item } -Properties *|Select mail
    $MailAdress = $User.mail

    Start-Sleep 2
    Send-MailMessage -to $MailAdress -From $FromAdress -subject 'testing' -Body $Body -BodyAsHtml -    smtpServer $SMTP -Credential $Creds -Port 25 -DeliveryNotificationOption OnFailure -Encoding $encoding

    #Debug log
    Write-Output "Sent mail to"+$User
}
```

The HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-    strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >

<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Message</h1>
    <h2>This is an example for a mail</h2>
    <br>
    <b>Do not Reply</b>
    <br>
    <h1>הודעה</h1>
    <h2>זוהי הודעה לדוגמא</h2>
    <br>
    <b>נא לא להגיב</b>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you save the HTML file with encoding UTF-8 with BOM ? Also, take out the spaces in `xhtml1-    strict.dtd`

Comment: The file itself may be encoded correctly, but I think you'll want a `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in there somewhere to specify for the HTML parser: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp . [Also maybe your existing `xml:lang` should not be set to English but to Hebrew](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-when-xmllang)?